# Routing in MVC is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am reading an ebook on MVC.
It have following examples but none of them are working.

`routes.MapRoute("", "X{controller}/{action}");`

```
routes.MapRoute("", "Public/{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Both of them will go to Home `controller` and index `action`

Link for First route: `http://localhost:14099/XHome/Index`

Link for Second route: `http://localhost:14099/Public/Home/Index`

The output of the both should be the same as per the example in the book. But when i'm trying the same it is not giving any result. i.e `resource cannot be found.` Am i doing anything wrong here?

Following is my code which i have written:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute("", "X{controller}/{action}");
            routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("", "Public/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing the routes after default which is wrong, so i had to write it before the default which is quite obvious.

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
    routes.MapRoute("", "X{controller}/{action}");
                routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                routes.MapRoute("", "Public/{controller}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

        }
```